# Hiding address bar in all browsers

Tags: javascript

I need to hide the address bar of all browsers through my JavaScript code. Is it possible to do?

Here is my code:

```
window.open("displayPdf.php?mnth="+mnth+"&year="+year+"&val="+newVal);
    dom.disable_window_open_feature.location
    dom.disable_window_open_feature.resizable
    dom.disable_window_open_feature.status
```

Comment: Do you want to hide the address bar of current winodw? Or you want to pop up another window in which address bar is hidden?

Comment: i want to hide the popup window addressbar............

Comment: Note that hiding an address bar is extremely user unfriendly. As an alternative you could display a message like 'Press F11 for fullscreen mode' (I believe F11 works in most browsers but correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: ya u r right buddy .....

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is no longer possible in modern browsers due to security restrictions.

Official(-ish) Sources:

- [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.open#Toolbar_and_chrome_features)

  > In Firefox 3, dom.disable_window_open_feature.location now defaults to true, forcing the presence of the Location Bar much like in IE7. See bug 337344 for more information.
- [Internet Explorer 7 and later](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536651%28VS.85%29.aspx)

  > In Internet Explorer 6, location specifies whether to display the Address Bar.

  (Implying the behaviour ends with IE6)
- [Chrome/Chromium](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=81506)

  > Those toolbar hiding parameters are ignored in Chrome.
  >   You will also notice that modern browsers are moving towards not hiding it as security / anti phishing measures.
  >   Also see https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=337344

Answer (score -4):

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "openwindow", "<script type=text/javascript> window.open('abc.aspx?id=" + str_id + "','null','location=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,addressbar=0,titlebar=no,directories=no,channelmode=no,status=no'); </script>");
```

Comment: please edit your answer and format the code to make it readable