# Customizing the features of "window.open" in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, dom-events

My Javascript code is,

```
var win = openBrWindow('http://www.w3schools.com','_blank','directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resize=no');"

win.resizeTo('792','115');
```

My window opens like:

[image]

But I need as:

[image]

My address bar occupies the some space which includes the already defined size.

So my loaded html page size will get decreased.

How to intimate the browser to add some more size when resizing the window, if the window has address bar?

Comment: Don't do this. You don't really get to choose how the browser shows your content; despite your best efforts, it'll probably wind up in a new tab anyways.

Comment: You could require the user to use chrome, and to use the site as an application. Or require them to use IE6 or older where you have more control over the popup window.

Comment: I'm not sure what the address bar has to do with the width/window size you are looking at. Have you tested this in all browsers to see the difference in each browser in the height of the address bar area? i'm pretty sure it varies from browser to browser a decent amount. Why not instead use a dialog, where you have far more control over the width/height of it? dialogs don't have forced title/address/status bars. Using a dialog + an iframe you can mimic the functionality you currently have.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible any more to avoid Phishing style attacks.  See also - [Hiding address bar in all browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16603308/hiding-address-bar-in-all-browsers) for a more informed answer.