# how to hide the address bar from script

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, bigbluebutton

In particular case, for security issue i want to hide my address bar or www.something.com should not display.

I am using rails 3.2.13, ruby 1.9.3.

```
 <%= link_to "Join session", join_bigbluebutton_rooms_path(@room)%>
```

This will redirect me to bigbluebuttonserver, exactly i want to hide the name of the url of this server. Because server and application is in my hand

Urlencode is not required in this case. I totally want to hide addressbar so that user cannot see the url address. How can i solve this, is it easy?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking - you want to hide the name of the url from _whom_? From the user? Sounds more like a javascript problem than a ruby problem...

Comment: Have you took a look at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16603308/hiding-address-bar-in-all-browsers
or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15926105/hiding-the-address-bar-of-a-browser
you should use an iframe

Comment: yes from users. How to hide the url from javascript?

Comment: i will check and let you know if it works