# Remove Buttons and address bar from popup

Tags: javascript, popupwindow

I'm trying this javascript code:

```
function PopupCenter(url, title, w, h)
{
    var left = (screen.width/2)-(w/2);
    var top = (screen.height/5)-(h/5);
    return window.open(url, title, 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width='+w+', height='+h+', top='+top+', left='+left);
}
```

I want to make a popup window from where I want to remove `Buttons` and `Address Bar`. I have mentioned these two areas in this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOPiQ.jpg

How to make the above code so it removes these two areas? Please help

Comment: This is not possible. Se this similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16603308/hiding-address-bar-in-all-browsers

Comment: OK, so is there any way I create a popup in javascript where these two areas shouldn't be shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look on these simple modal windows: http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal-demos/ You may also define your own CSS to customize to suite to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can't remove this buttons and address bars for IE 7+

> In Internet Explorer 7 and later, you cannot remove the address bar in Internet Zone windows, for security (anti-spoofing) reasons.

Comment: OK, so is there any way I create a popup in javascript where these two areas shouldn't be shown?

Comment: You can't create a PopUp window without buttons and address bar. But you can try something like **JQuery ModalBox** or Splash window. If you google **Jquery Splash Window** or **JQuery Modal Box** you can find something.