# I want to open new window with no address bar

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var myWindow = window.open("","myWindow","ttilebar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,width=306,height=325,margin-top:0px,margin-left=0px,left="+left+"px, top="+top+"px,toolbar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no");
    myWindow.document.write('<iframe style="width:306px;height:342px;" id="CCBox"'
            + 'class="ifti1" src="http://localhost:8089/clientChatbox?user='
            + encodeURI(JSON.stringify(user))
            + '"frameborder="0" '
            + '></iframe>');
```

I want to open it in with no title and no address bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of security issue, this may not be possible now in all modern browsers. Look at below urls for more details:

[Hiding address bar in all browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16603308/hiding-address-bar-in-all-browsers)

[Open new popup window without address bars in firefox & IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909645/open-new-popup-window-without-address-bars-in-firefox-ie)

Answer (score 0):

Courtesy: [Comment from Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15926179/4948688)

It's different in every browser.

Some years ago, what you tried, was right. But nowadays it is regarded as a security risk that one cannot see the browsers address bar and (for phishing reasons) and so they (or most of them) made the decision to always show the browser address bar.

Comment: i just want to open it in IE . Is there any way to do it??

Comment: Way 1:
In internet explorer, if the new url is from the same domain as the current url, the window will be open without an address bar. Otherwise, it will cause an address bar to appear. One workaround is to open a page from the same domain and then redirect from that page.

Way2:
Open a modal popup window and embed the external URL as an iframe.

Comment: that's what i am doing. opening a popup window and then embedding the iframe . But it is not working. Address bar is still there.